# Updating a model in a collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, javascript-framework, backbone-events

My question is how would you update a model in a collection? Here is what I am doing. On page load I fetch a list of contacts. In one view I list out these contacts in an unordered list. Each contact is clickable which will take you to an edit form. Once you make changes to the contact you can save the contact. This will take you to a method that save the altered model back to the collection. How would you do this? In the backbone docs there isn't an update method (or at least I don't see it). I created a way to do this but I am not sure if it is the preferred Backbone way. Here it is:

```
        updatePlan : function()
        {
            //unique ID of the model
            var id = $( 'input[ name=id ]' ).val();
            //remove the old model from the collection
            this.collection.remove( this.model );
            //add the updated model to the collection
            this.collection.add( this.model );              

        }
```

You would think there would be a function like this:

```
        updatePlan : function()
        {
            this.collection.update( this.model );

        }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can have your view that allows the user to edit the contact update the model for you. And since the model gets passed by reference, it will also be updated in the collection that it is a part of.

Here's an example.

```
EditView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'change #name': 'nameChanged',
    'change #age': 'ageChanged'
  },
  render: function() {
    //render code
  },
  nameChanged: function() {
    var nameValue = this.$('#name').val();
    this.model.set({ Name : nameValue });
  },
  ageChanged: function() {
    var ageValue = this.$('#age').val();
    this.model.set({ Age : ageValue });
  }
}
```

And then when you create the edit view, you pass in the selected model from the collection

```
selectedContact = contactCollection.at(0);
var editView = new EditView({ model: contact });
$('#editDiv').html(editView.render().el);
```

The only thing left to do is to save the model to the server when the user clicks the save button.

```
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
  selectedContact.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paul, you should have a View for your collection, and a View for your model.
The view for the model allows you to edit your model and the save should propagate up correctly.

However that said you seem to have a view there that has 1 model and 1 collection (based on your remove and add this.model) so you have a view that is displaying a single model... I assume :D

You could then do this.

```
    updatePlan : function()
    {
        //unique ID of the model
        var id = $( 'input[ name=id ]' ).val();
        this.model.set({id: id});
        this.model.save();
    }
```

I think the issue might then just be your initial "logic", you don't edit a model within a collection.
You edit a model, that model just happens to belong to a collection. 
So events will fire for both the model and the model.collection, like on your set of id, the Change:id event will fire and trigger any binding to either your model its collections

Hope it helps :)